# Is there a way to have Safari View Controller embedded in a navigation controller but still have Safari View Controller's navigation gestures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to push Safari View Controller onto my UINavigationController but when I do, the "go back"/"go forward" slide gestures in the browser are disabled, which doesn't happen when it's presented modally.

Is there a way to push it onto the navigation stack but not have Safari's gestures disabled?